# How To Silence Evocation Fangs?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing around with the `/summon` command, and I stumbled upon evocation fangs. I then typed in a command into a command block: `/summon evocation_fangs sawblade ~~1~`. This created a sort of sawblade:
[image]

Unfortunately, this saw-blade is *quite loud*! How do I mute the evocation fangs while keeping ambient sounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `stopsound` command.

```
stopsound @s mob.evocation_fangs.attack
```

---

#### The Command

The `stopsound` command can be utilized to, stop sounds. The syntax for this command in Bedrock Edition is:

```
stopsound <player> [sound]
```

While `player` is required, `sound` is optional, per [DigMinecraft](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/stopsound_command.php):

> ###### Definitions
>
> - `player` is the name of the player (or a target selector) that you wish to stop the sound effect for.
> - `sound` is optional. It is the sound effect to stop. (See [List of Sound Effect Names](https://www.digminecraft.com/lists/sound_list_pc.php).)

#### Evocation Sounds

There are several sound effects related to evocation:

| ID | Sound |
| --- | --- |
| mob.evocation_fangs.attack | sounds/mob/evocation_illager/fangs hostile |
| mob.evocation_illager.ambient | sounds/mob/evocation_illager/idle1 sounds/mob/evocation_illager/idle2 sounds/mob/evocation_illager/idle3 sounds/mob/evocation_illager/idle4 |
| mob.evocation_illager.cast_spell | sounds/mob/evocation_illager/cast1 sounds/mob/evocation_illager/cast2 |
| mob.evocation_illager.celebrate | sounds/mob/evocation_illager/celebrate sounds/mob/evocation_illager/idle1 sounds/mob/evocation_illager/idle2 – |
| mob.evocation_illager.death | sounds/mob/evocation_illager/death1 sounds/mob/evocation_illager/death2 |
| mob.evocation_illager.hurt | sounds/mob/evocation_illager/hurt1 sounds/mob/evocation_illager/hurt2 |
| mob.evocation_illager.prepare_attack | sounds/mob/evocation_illager/prepare_attack1 sounds/mob/evocation_illager/prepare_attack2 |
| mob.evocation_illager.prepare_summon | sounds/mob/evocation_illager/prepare_summon |
| mob.evocation_illager.prepare_wololo | sounds/mob/evocation_illager/prepare_wololo |

The one you're interested in is `mob.evocation_fangs.attack`.

#### Setup

You'll need an additional command block, set to always repeat unconditionally, at a faster rate than your summoning command block. This additional command block should have it's command set to:

```
stopsound @a[r=5] mob.evocation_fangs.attack
```

This was my setup:

[image: Screenshot of my setup in Minecraft.]

You can remove the radius argument if you'd like, I just limited the command to all players in the immediate area.

##### Final Note

Unfortunately, chaining the command block isn't fast enough as the sound effect has enough time to trigger before the secondary command block. While it will muffle the sound, it won't eradicate it unless it's a separate command block with a faster rate than the summoning.

Comment: Thanks! It works partially; there seems to be a weird clicking noise, but it can barely be heard. I will still mark this as accepted. Again, thank you!